# In the login form, long passwords makes the "forgot?" action link look ugly

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, login

Because an image says more than a thousand words:

[image]

Notice how, when a user has a long password, the password masking dots overlap with the "forgot?" link, which looks quite ugly.

**The "forgot?" link should be somehow moved out of the way of the password entry.**

One possible way of fixing this could be hiding the "forgot?" link once the user has typed a few characters into the password field, because at that point the user obviously at least *thinks* that they remember their password, at which point the "forgot?" link is no longer particularly relevant to that login attempt.

Comment: Yeah, that's a fair point... We're currently running a split test involving this UI, so I'm not inclined to make changes until it's over, but we'll move the link to live below the input box once again when the test is done.

Comment: @AnnaLear I kind of like having the link inside the password field. It makes it very clear that it's about forgotten passwords, without needing a lot of extra description in place. It's just that the password-masking dots overlap with the link when the password is long, which IMO is ugly. (Always encourage long passwords!) That seems like it should be fixable with a tiny bit of Javascript and fairly minimal testing...

Comment: All my testing is minimal. ;) Seriously, though, I'm not sure I like hiding the link just based on the length of text in the password field. That seems weird to me in a different way. [Current implementation](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VeKoG.png) is still pretty succinct, IMO, without suffering from either a bad overlap or accidental undiscoverability (or tapping on mobile devices), although there *is* a bit of missing padding.

Comment: @AnnaLear I see your point. :-) Either way, I would strongly recommend moving it out of the way of the password entry. Exactly how you do that is up to you people.